# Why did Eleven say goodbye to Mike if she knew she could go back?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

In season 1 of *Stranger Things*, shortly before killing the Demogorgon, El says goodbye to Mike and disappears. In season 2, right after the kill, she seems to be surprised to be in the Upside Down and calls out for Mike there. When she gets to the real world, she tries to contact him right away before seeing that the police are looking for her.

Why such a tearful goodbye in season 1, then?

Comment: I think she expected to die.

Comment: Just because she *did* survive doesn't mean she *knew she would*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because she can't predict future. She had no idea that she can leave that easily or even survive in Upside down.

So that goodbye was tearful because it was Eleven's separation from Mike she was so attached with.